# Android detect the long key press of a button

Tags: android, keyevent

I using a remote control to access the device.

In my case when i press any button on keydown and on keyup events are called continuously.

I think onkey up event should be called only during the release of  the key but its called during the the pressing of the button.

**Is there any way to solve this problem or alternative solution to track the onkey long press ?**

Comment: Are you looking for `setOnLongClickListener`?

Comment: NO,i am looking for on onkeylong press for hard keys in the device.

Answer (score 1):

```
long lastDown;
long keyPressedDuration ;

button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           keyPressedDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
        }
     }
  };
```

Comment: I am using the hard keys in remote is it possible to use this method.